# How To Convert a function value (bytes) to decimal values (0-255 each)

Tags: php, function, byte

i'm implementing a ProvablyFair algorithm. One of the steps is to get the first four bytes of a hashed value as separate integers.

here is what I've attempted till here:

```
  <?php
$K = "95ac4ed338c4b1e9ce4a0e2fb7bb400fa7f3ee5e62264432acb37e27619fe2ec";
$clientSeed = 98889;
$nonce = 21;
$row_number = 1;
$message = "{$clientSeed}:{$nonce}:{$row_number}:0";
$goHash = hash_hmac('sha256', $K, $message);
echo "Hash : " . $goHash;
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
printf("%s\n", "Bin To Hex : " . bin2hex($goHash));
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
$byte_array = array_values(unpack('C*', $goHash));
echo "First 4 Bytes (Array) : ";
$Get_1St_4_Bytes = (array_slice($byte_array, 0, 4));
print_r($Get_1St_4_Bytes);
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
$byte1 = $Get_1St_4_Bytes[0];
$byte2 = $Get_1St_4_Bytes[1];
$byte3 = $Get_1St_4_Bytes[2];
$byte4 = $Get_1St_4_Bytes[3];

echo "First 4 Bytes : "."[$byte1]  [$byte2]  [$byte3] [$byte4]";
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
echo octdec($byte1);
echo "<br>";
```

but the next step is : The first four bytes of the HMAC_SHA256($K, $message) function’s result need to be converted into decimal values (0-255 each).

how to convert `$byte1` , `$byte2` , `$byte3` , `$byte4` to decimal values ?

Comment: Do you mean like [`hexdec()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hexdec.php)?

Comment: i want a function to convert $byte1 . $byte2 . $byte3 . $byte4 to decimal values

Answer (score 1):

$byte1 , $byte2 , $byte3 , $byte4 **are** the decimal values.

You could also shorten this line:

```
$byte_array = array_values(unpack('C*', $goHash));
```

to

```
$byte_array = unpack('C4', $goHash);   // with 4 instead of * you get the first 4 bytes
```

Comment: in guidelines . the target is .  The first four bytes of the HMAC_SHA256($K, $message) function’s result need to be converted into decimal values (0-255 each).
 and we have each bytes in byte1 ... byte4  , then we need to convert do decimal for each . any idea?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by converting bytes into decimal values. $byte1 , $byte2 , $byte3 , and $byte4 are already decimal values when you use unpack().

Comment: so is unpack function  for converting to decimal values? or it uses for getting bytes of values?

Comment: A byte is a decimal value. Maybe you could elaborate what you think that the decimal conversion of some example byte would be.